# Postgres string truncation at the table-level schema

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, hibernate

I have a table in Postgres with the following schema:

```
create table if not exists cars
(
  id bigserial not null,
  tyre_code varchar(8)
);
```

The `tyre_code` in the table should ideally not be more than 8 characters in length. But, in the case that someone does provide a string that is greater than 8 characters, is there a way at the table-level schema in Postgres to truncate the value of this string and insert it? The other option I have is to truncate the value in the Java code and then insert it. However, that is not ideal, and would prefer is I can do this at the table level itself.

```
For example:
tyre_code provided - ABCDEFGHIJK
tyre_code after truncation - ABCDEFGH
```

I am using Postgres, with Spring and Hibernate. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: That what a varchar (8) does, it truncates the content

Comment: Perhaps a bigger question is: When a string longer that 8 characters is submitted how do you know the most left 8 characters is the correct value?  Answer: You do and cannot know. IMHO it is better to let the exception occur rather than store potentially erroneous data.

Answer (score 2):

With your existing table definition OR after adding check constraints for length; If you try to insert column value more than 8 characters;
It shall throw you error as :

> "value too long"

But;

You can achieve it using : `BEFORE INSERT trigger` as follows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION truncate_tyre_code()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.tyre_code = LEFT(NEW.tyre_code, 8);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER truncate_tyre_code_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON cars
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION truncate_tyre_code();
```

===============================================================
Also if you are looking for adding constraints to check column length in postgresql; Then you may try : [CHECK constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  tyre_code varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT truncated_tyre_code CHECK (LENGTH(tyre_code) <= 8)
);
```

Here is a [working demo using DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/OAxjSmA0)

In more simplified way as :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  tyre_code varchar(8) CHECK (LENGTH(tyre_code) <= 8) NOT NULL
);
```

Here is a [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ANTgWEyV)

Assuming you already have a table structure as follows :

```
create table if not exists cars
(
  id bigserial not null,
  tyre_code varchar(8)
);
```

To add an extra constraint in `alter table` statement.

```
ALTER TABLE cars ADD CONSTRAINT truncated_tyre_code CHECK (LENGTH(tyre_code) <= 8);
```

[ALTER (EXISTING) TABLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/i4FwQFGj)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to do what you mentioned in the first method. I copied the code you mentioned and when I try to insert I still get the error saying " value too long for type character varying(8)".

Comment: Yes, It will throw you "value too long";

Instead; Can you try the trigger I wrote ?

The other OP also has written a trigger.

You can try any of it

Comment: I did try the trigger you wrote, but for some reason it does not work and does not truncate the string. So, when I try and insert a value longer than 8 characters, it gives me an error of value too long instead of truncating the string and inserting only 8 characters.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with `varchar(8)` vs `text`?

Answer (score 2):

Define the column as type `text` (no length limit) with a check constraint that enforces the length. Then use a `BEFORE` trigger to truncate the value:

```
CREATE TABLE varlen (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   val text CHECK (length(val) <= 8) NOT NULL
);

CREATE FUNCTION trunc_val() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   NEW.val := left(NEW.val, 8);
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER trunc_val BEFORE INSERT ON varlen
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trunc_val();

INSERT INTO varlen VALUES (1, 'a string that exceeds 8 characters');

TABLE varlen;

 id │   val    
════╪══════════
  1 │ a string
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason you defined the column as type `text` and not `varchar(8)`? Will this method not work with `varchar(8)`?

Comment: Yes, it will not work with `varchar(8)`, because then the error would be thrown *before* the trigger has a chance to run. But be at ease: `text` and `varchar` are really the same in PostgreSQL